# Is there a way to convert a pandas dataframe into a table view in sql in Databricks?

Tags: python, sql, databricks

I have a series of analyses I need to perform in Databricks starting from SQL queries, and then passing onto Python.

Once I am done I need to download the DataFrames I am creating into my local computer, but that seems fairly complicated because I can't seem to download the files from the DBFS. I thought then that if I could create a view with SQL I could just use the download button (that is unavailable with DataFrames).

Does anybody have any suggestion on this? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you possibly provide the code associated with what you're doing, would help with figuring out what you're trying to produce?

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the internet that went from a Pandas DataFrame onto a create view in SQL, so I have no code to show unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

Within your databricks workbook, this will create a table called "table_name" within the existing database called "my_data" from an existing dataframe called "df".

```
%python
df.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("my_data.table_name")
```

From there, then write your SQL query to export the table contents as CSV.